# NullPointerException for JMeterPluginsCMD

Tags: java, jmeter

Running this command:
sh bin/JMeterPluginsCMD.sh --generate-csv aggregate-report.csv --input-jtl summary.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport

Getting an exception:

```
2017-07-07T23:48:27,865 INFO  [main] org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_US
ERROR: java.lang.NullPointerException
*** Problem's technical details go below ***
Home directory was detected as: src/test/jmeter/lib
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.initializeProperties(PluginsCMDWorker.java:118)
    at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.prepareJMeterEnv(PluginsCMDWorker.java:81)
    at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.<init>(PluginsCMDWorker.java:55)
    at kg.apc.cmdtools.ReporterTool.processParams(ReporterTool.java:64)
    at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:66)
    at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at kg.apc.cmd.UniversalRunner.main(UniversalRunner.java:105)
```

I used to have a lot of different errors like `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jorphan/logging/LoggingManager`
or `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.AggregateReportGui`
. And I was able to resolve those by adding needed .jar files. 
But I totally don't understand how to fix this NullPointerException.

Comment: I guess, you'll need to look into the source code.

Answer (score 2):

Install **Synthesis Report** plugin from - https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SynthesisReport/

Answer (score 0):

When you [download](https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-cmd) you need to copy lib folder also to jmeter/lib

Comment: I did that, I copied all the files to the corresponding folders.